# Bar chart horizontal bar width i want fixed or max width for each horizontal bar

Tags: bar-chart, morris.js

I am using morris.js to create bar chart.But the size of bar is too wide.
Can you suggest how can i restrict the bar size?

[image: You can find screen shot of chart here]

Using the Java Script Code

```
  var bar = new Morris.Bar({
      element: 'bar-chart',
      resize: true,
      data: [
        {y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90}
      ],
      barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
      labels: ['CPU', 'DISK'],
      hideHover: 'auto'
    });
```

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with it? Too wide? Too tall? We have no idea what your scale is supposed to be, how you created it, etc. The only thing we know, from what you posted, is that you have a bar chart.

Comment: Sorry about that,I have added more information in my question now.

Comment: I see you edited your question, but you also undid an important edit someone else did, and changed your image back to a link (I corrected this once again). Nobody should have to click a link to see the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use barSizeRatio to control the width of the bars. So, when you have few bars e.g. less than 5, set barSizeRatio to 0.2. For more than 5 bars, let don't specify barSizeRatio, let the chart control figure it out.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bv4xezh7/1/

```
Morris.Bar({
 barSizeRatio:0.2,
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { date: '04-02-2014', value: 3 },
    { date: '04-03-2014', value: 10 },

  ],
  xkey: 'date',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['Orders']
});
```

You can make it more dynamic by figuring out the width of the chart control and then decide the value of barSizeRatio to meet your maximum bar width criteria.